# more than one type in Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

I've been wondering how can i create an `arraylist` in java that can hold different types (integer + string)
and some string variables will be from different classes 
my variables are

`day: string, time: int, section: Sections(string), doctor: Doctors(string), patient: Patients(string), AppointmentNo: int`

Comment: Java is to JavaScript [as ham is to hamster](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/).

Comment: You can use ArrayList<Object>, but you probably shouldn't. It sounds like you should create a new class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the proper way, but you can do something like this,

```
    ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    objects.add(1);
    objects.add("asd");
```

The better way is to create a different class with the attributes with Strings and int values you want. Then create an array with the type of that class and add those objects to the array.

Answer (score 0):

First, you would have to **create your own class to hold such datatypes** like the `String` and `int`. You would do it like this:

```
public class MyCustomItems{
    private String doctors;
    private String patient;
    private int appointmentNo;

    public MyCustomItems(String doctors, String patient, int num) {
        this.doctors = doctors;
        this.patient= patient;
        this.appointmentNo = num
    } 

    public String getDoctors() {
        return doctors;
    }

    public void setDoctors(String d) {
        this.doctors= d;
    }

    public void setPatient(String p) {
        this.patient= p;
    }

    public void setNum(int n) {
        this.num= n;
    }

    public String getPatient() {
        return patient;
    }

    public String getAppointment() {
        return appointmentNo;
    }
}
```

Then, you would have to **create an ArrayList** and the **ArrayList type will be the class** that you have just made.
It should look like this:

```
ArrayList<MyCustomItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new MyCustomItem("Doctor 1", "Patient 1", 1));
```

When adding a new value to `arrayList`, you will have to use the `new MyCustomItem(string, string, int)` in order to pass in those values because in the `MyCustomItem` class, the constructor requires two Strings and one int. Now, each position in `arrayList` will hold an object of the `MyCustomItem` class meaning that each position will not contain just one int or one String, but it will contain 2 Strings and one int.

This is how you would do it. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Create class with the fields you specified in the question:

```
public class Appointment {
    String day;
    int time;
    String section;
    String doctor;
    String patient;
    int appointmentNo;

    public Appointment() {
    }
}
```

and next create array list with Appointment objects:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<>();
    appointments.add(new Appointment());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the purpose of arrays. **An array is a data structure that contains a fixed-sized* collection of elements of a specific data type.** ([link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_programming/computer_programming_arrays.htm))

Let's say you accomplished storing a `string`, `int`, and an `object` in the array.

```
const foo = [ 
  "Jan 1st, 1970", 
  1542824996, 
  { name: "Foo" },
]
```

so far it might be fine, as you can tell how this data is related, but what if you add more:

```
const bar = [ 
  "Jan 1st, 1970", 
  1542824996, 
  { name: "Foo" }, 
  "Jan 2nd, 1970", 
  1542824000, 
  { ... } 
]
```

or even worse, if you have this:

```
const bar = [ 
  "Jan 1st, 1970", 
  "Jan 2nd, 1970", 
  1542824996, 
  1542824000, 
  { name: "Foo" }, 
  { ... } 
]
```

with only 2 entries, your data structure lost its purpose (organization of data). This is why we use `objects`, and store similar objects in arrays. Like so:

```
// FooBar Class Declaration
class FooBar {
  public date;
  public time;
  public options;

  constructor(date: string, time: int, options: object) {
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.options = options;
  }  
}

// Constructing the `FooBar` object
const fB1 = new FooBar("Jan 1st, 1970", 1542824996, { name: "Foo" });
const fB2 = new FooBar("Jan 2nd, 1970", 1542824000, { ... });

// Storing the objects in an array
const fooBarContainer = [ fB1, fB2 ];
```

Now it's clear what the relationships inside the objects are, and you get all the array benefits of sorting, filtering, mapping, etc.

**Answer:** You should first organize your data in logically relevant constructs, then store it in an array.